# Link on z-indexed div not a link?

Tags: html, css, anchor, z-index

I have a div behind the main div.  Sometimes it appears and sometimes it's occluded, and that's fine.  But the link on that z-indexed div isn't showing up as a link.  Which is to say, the browser doesn't turn the cursor to a pointer; and when you click on it, it doesn't request the href document.

Is there any way to keep the div so that it gets occluded when the browser is resized, but still gives us the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.

I was using negative z-index values, which puts the div behind the body and is therefore unreachable.  When I used the same relative values for main div and background div, but made them positive, it all worked.

Hope this helps someone else.